# React component appears and disappears instantly in conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, conditional-rendering

For following scenario :

When user don't have admin access, else case is rendering and disappearing instantly after it.
I can see blank page only after it.
How to resolve this scenario ?

```
function Component () {
   const isAdmin = checkIsAdmin('user')

   return (
         { isAdmin ? (
             return <div>Show admin page</div>
           ) : (
             return <h1>You are not autherized</h1>
           )

         }
   )
}
```

Comment: Based on that code it's difficult to tell. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002). Include the component that renders `Component`, and the `isAdmin` function.

Comment: I'm guessing the default value for `isAdmin` is `true` therefore it'll show for a brief second until `checkIsAdmin` completes the check and returns (which happens to be false).

Comment: @selected I have inspected value in both scenario. value is false in both case.

Comment: Hard to say without more info, you mentioned you're seeing a blank page; are there any errors in the console? also I would remove the `return` keywords and the surrounding brackets all together, so you end up with `isAdmin ? <div>is admin</div> : <div>is not admin</div>`